# Morris bar chart, show 2 colors in 1 line, negative and positive

Tags: javascript, css, morris.js

I have a Morris bar chart that show positive and negative results.

What do i want to achieve is to make 2 colors, one for negative and one for positive results like on a images below.

I looked into documentation and didn't find any solution to this.

Is this possible or not ?

Here is a current code:

```
var positiveColor = 'orange';   //'#32CD32';
var negativeColor = 'grey';     //'#FF6347';

Morris.Bar({
  element: 'morris-bar2',
  barColors: [positiveColor, negativeColor],
  data: <?php echo $json_data2; ?>,
  stacked: false,
  resize: true,
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a'],
  labels: ['Total', ''],
  hideHover: false,
  gridTextColor: '#4F5F6F',
  gridTextSize: '12'
});
```

Examples:

Current bar color
[image]

Need to be like

[image]

Comment: What does your data look like?

Comment: like this ``data: [{"y":"Aug","a":"-3297.289999999999","b":""},{"y":"Sep","a":"2534.1600000000008","b":""},{"y":"Oct","a":"-11859.449999999997","b":""},{"y":"Nov","a":"-6653.5999999999985","b":""}],``

Answer (score 5, accepted):

according to [one of the examples on GitHub](https://github.com/morrisjs/morris.js/blob/master/examples/bar-colors.html#L33), you can use a callback for the `barColors` property.

So, you could do something like this:

```
barColors: function (row, series, type) {
    if (row.y < 0)
        return "grey";
    return "orange";
}
```

Comment: orange color is all time here

Comment: Try with `row.y` instead of `row.a`

Comment: Can you put `console.log(row);` in that function and post the output?

Comment: @Jerodev: Your solution is correct except `row.a`. I tried with `row.y` and it's working.

Comment: Yay! Glad I could help! Consider marking this answer as the solution if this solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always use this code

```
 ykeys: ['positive', 'negative'],
 barColors: ['#00cccc', '#3300cc'],
```

and it just an example

complete example of what I have;

```
var bar = new Morris.Bar({
  element: 'chart',
  resize: true,
  data:[<?php echo $chart_data; ?>],
  barColors: ['#00cccc', '#3300cc'],
  xkey: 'date',
  ykeys: ['Positive', 'Negative'],
  labels: ['Positive Value', 'Negative Value '],
  hideHover: 'auto'
});
```